# Angular mat-grid-tile color not applying

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular 8 mat-grid-list that contains several mat-grid-tiles that have a hardcoded background color of red. However, this color is not applied to the tiles.

I've tried changing the color to several other values too, to no avail.
Everything works fine, except the color that is not applied.

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let element of workspaces"
[colspan]="1"
[rowspan]="1"
[style.background]="red">
{{element.name}}
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Here is the current output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the apostrophes. Change the `"red"` to `"'red'"`